# Passing CSV columns to a command in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a csv file (separated by comma), just as:

```
file1.txt,file1.tsv
file2.txt,file2.tsv
file3.txt,file3.tsv
```

And I want to pass them to a command that accepts multiple files such as, for example:

```
myscript.py \
--txt file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \
--tsv file1.tsv file2.tsv file3.tsv
```

Is there any way to paste the values from the first column after --txt and the values of the second column after --tsv in command line or in a script?

I have thousands of lines, that's why I wanted a way to to this, but I have no clue where to start

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Are the leading spaces part of the file? If not, please remove them in your question.

Comment: Yes, but to no avail. I wasn't even close so I didn't include anything that would make the question worse!

Comment: note that a command longer than some particular number of characters (`getconf ARG_MAX` on posix systems) will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way with bash:

```
mapfile -t flist <in.csv
myscript.py --txt "${flist[@]%,*}" --tsv "${flist[@]#*,}"
```

Comment: I kinda like the array way so I can manipulate values and I'm getting used to it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create arrays of all the filenames and fill them in from the CSV columns.

```
txts=()
tsvs=()
while IFS=, read -r txt tsv 
do
    txts+=("$txt")
    tsvs+=("$tsv")
done < input.csv

myscript.py --txt "${txts[@]}" --tsv "${tsvs[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myscript.py \
--txt $(awk -F, '{printf "%s ",$1}' inputfile) \
--tsv $(awk -F, '{printf "%s ",$2}' inputfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for fun (assuming csv file is named test.csv):

```
myscript.py \
--txt `cut -d',' -f1 test.csv|tr '\r\n' ' '` \
--tsv `cut -d',' -f2 test.csv|tr '\r\n' ' '`
```

Less efficient than others since it does read the file twice.